# Heroku rails console does not start any more

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, console

I have an issue with running the rails console at heroku (cedar-stack). Each of the following commands heroku run console, heroku run rails console, heroku run bundle exec rails console results in the following error-message:

Running `bundle exec rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.8155

Abort testing: Your Rails environment is running in production mode!

This error-message is a little bit confused. What kind of test tries heroku to start? I just want to fire up the console, which had worked fine 4 weeks ago.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which command are you trying to run? `heroku run rails console`?

Comment: I just want to enter the rails console for my app hosted at heroku.com via Git-bash

Comment: OK I got it right now: using "heroku run console development" does the job. But I'm wondering about this. Is this default behaviour ?

Comment: By the way calling "heroku run console production" results in the same error-message and aborts too

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing the heroku console in development environment. A heroku app runs in production so I don't see why you should need to access it in development. You should contact them or file an issue.

Comment: I don't want to access it in development mode ! But the other way, it does not work. This is the issue I tried to tell you.

Answer (score 46):

For Cedar Stack and later:

```
heroku run rails console --app <app name>
```

Previous stacks could use this command:

```
heroku run console --app <app name>
```

Comment: Awesome. Great to hear. You might also want to take a look at the heroku_san gem. It help in giving a bunch of environment specific rake tasks to console in, deploy, or hooks to perform before/after deploy.

Comment: Note: if you are on Cedar, you will need to do 'heroku run rails console --app <app name>

Answer (score 19):

If you have multiple environments (staging / production / etc) you need this command:

```
heroku run -a app-name console
```

If you only have a single environment and never setup staging or other environments you can just run:

```
heroku run console
```

https://github.com/nemrow/rails_app_cheatsheet/blob/master/heroku.rdoc

Answer (score 3):

For some reason you need to explicitly define the console process in the `Procfile`:

```
# Procfile

web: script/rails server -p $PORT
console: script/rails console
```

This blog post has more details: http://platypus.belighted.com/blog/2013/01/21/ruby-2-rails-4-heroku/

Comment: you don't have to do this (anymore?). for me all you have to do is `heroku run script/rails console`

Comment: This is no longer valid on Rails 4.0.0 as it removes script/rails in favor of bin/rails.

Answer (score 3):

I was with the same problem and I decided to do this and it worked

```
$ heroku run bash
$ cd bin
~/bin $ ruby rails console
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `heroku run console` as others have answered.

Heroku only runs in one environment at a time, [which is configured by the RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV environments variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#production-and-development-modes).

When you connect, the console will use the correct environment automatically.