# Rails app works locally, has critical errors on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm using heroku for the first time today and I have a few questions.  The app pushed fine, but upon trying to go to the URL, or running "heroku run rails console" I get the following errors.

```
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- ./string_utilities (LoadError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have a file called string_utilities.rb that is a module. I reference in my app as

```
    include StringUtilities
```

This file is merely stored in a created folder we made, so I'm guessing it's not being served in production.

How can I directly serve this file in production?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472981/heroku-rails-console-does-not-start-any-more

Comment: @BroiSatse yes but I also get these errors when just trying to go to the page through the URL, it's not just with console.  Could it be that my procfile doesn't have an environment set?  Or does rails default to something?  this is what it says: web bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p $PORT

Comment: What do you have in your environment file, 5th line?

Comment: @BroiSatse This is the entire file:

 # Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Getwell3::Application.initialize!

Getwell3::Application.config.force_ssl = true

Comment: have you followed those steps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4? Especially, have you added `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` to your gemfile, are you using postgres db, have you specified your ruby version?

Comment: @BroiSatse Actually I think the issue is with a file we have in AppName>app>classes.  It's called string_utilities, which corresponds to the error above.  Could it be that this file is not being sent while rails is in production mode? How can we set our require statements to include an absolute path to the file in question?

Comment: where you do a call to precess the file **string_utilities**, apply: `File.expand_path(Rails.root, ./string_utilities)` if you use rails 3.x, 4.x

Comment: @majioa so right now I have include StringUtilities.  should it be include include File.expand_path(Rails.root, ./string_utilities) ?  I'm on rails 3.x

Comment: @majioa I fixed the question to more accurately reflect what's going on.

Comment: where the file **string_utilities.rb** is resided in your repo, show all the relative path to it.  And I guess that `include StringUtilities` is not that line, which the error takes place in.

Comment: @majioa I'm not sure I'm getting exactly what you're saying, should I be defining this file in some type of config file? I'm not sure how I show the relative path to the file in question. I'd rather define it in some config file so I can keep the reference I'm using

Comment: The error above says that heroku can't the file, your local app works because you start it from console string in rails root `= './'`, but not heroku, it starts the app from another folder, and in order to find the file the app shell know its place from rails root. Or you just move it to app's `lib/` folder. and enable library loading in the rails config. Is the file **string_utilities.rb** resided in root of your rails app?

Comment: @majioa no it's in /app/classes.  We created the folder /app/classes, so I know Rails isn't loading it.  I'm not sure why it's looking for it in the root directory though.  Is it because all of files manually created like that get thrown into the root for development mode?

Comment: @majioa is the lib where it's supposed to go?  I have a module with methods in a separate rb file. I'm sure there's a better place for it than the folder I created, what would be the right location?

Comment: A couple of things come to mind that might cause this. First check that you haven’t forgotten to commit and push the file to Heroku. Second, if you are developing on Windows or Mac check that the file name isn’t actually something like `String_Utils.rb`, i.e. check that it is lower case.

Comment: Just put the files that are resided in app/classes into lib/ and configure rails to load it, it can be done by uncommenting one of the parameters in environment config. For heroku make sure that it is done for production

Comment: @majioa I actually just realized I have this in the config, config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/classes).  So it should be loading it.  How can I make sure it loads this during production? I'm not sure where to define that

Comment: @majioa If I add config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/classes) to /app/config/environments/production.rb, should that work?

Comment: @jamesdlivesinatree yes, it should